# Clojure spec "conformer" function, what is it?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

The `clojure.spec.alpha` API has a macro called [`conformer`](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/conformer) with this description:

> ```
> Usage: (conformer f)
>        (conformer f unf)
>
> takes a predicate function with the semantics of conform i.e. it should
> return either a (possibly converted) value or :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid,
> and returns a spec that uses it as a predicate/conformer. Optionally takes
> a second fn that does unform of result of first
> ```

This is unclear to me, if not esoteric.

What is it used for? What is the "unformer" (shouldn't that be an "unconformer") used for? I suppose to recreate the original data from the returned "conformed value"?.

**Update**

After 15 minutes of experiment, it seems to be to create a new "spec" from a "predicate" (the "spec" having something special going??)

I tried

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s :refer [valid? explain conform conformer]])

; ---
; Using purely clojure.spec.alpha:
; ---

(s/def ::vtx-x float?)  
(s/def ::vtx-y float?)
(s/def ::vertex (s/keys :req [::vtx-x ::vtx-y]))

(type (s/get-spec ::vertex))
;=> clojure.spec.alpha$map_spec_impl$reify__1997

(conform ::vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0 })
;=> #:user{:vtx-x 1.0, :vtx-y 2.0}

(valid? ::vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0 })
;=> true

(conform ::vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 })
;=> :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

; ---
; Using my own special sauce predicate function, where the conformed
; value carries additional information ... maybe for a debugging system?
; ---

(defn my-vertex-conformer [v]
   (when-let [ { x ::vtx-x y ::vtx-y } v ]
      (if (and (float? x) (float? y)) 
         [:comment "Vertex conforms!" :something (+ x y) :orig v]
         ; else
         :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid)))

(defn my-vertex-unformer [conf-v] (get conf-v :orig))

(s/def ::my-vertex (conformer my-vertex-conformer my-vertex-unformer))

(type (s/get-spec ::my-vertex))
;=> clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl$reify__2059

(conform ::my-vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0 })
;=> [:comment "Vertex conforms!" :something 3.0 
;=>         :orig #:user{:vtx-x 1.0, :vtx-y 2.0}]

(valid? ::my-vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0 })
;=> true

(conform ::my-vertex { ::vtx-x 1.0 })
;=> :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
```

Bonus, amazingly no exception here, is this an oversight?

```
(conformer map?)
;=> #object[clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl$reify__2059 0x770b843 "clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl$reify__2059@770b843"]

(type (conformer map?))
;=> clojure.spec.alpha$spec_impl$reify__2059
```

Comment: I really like the spec, apparently it has moved to Elixir, too: https://github.com/vic/spec - where does it come from intially?

Comment: Toy example here: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/conformer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is it used for?

For creating a spec which (when used to conform a value) can return a different value than it was given.

```
(s/conform str 1)
=> 1   ;; (str 1) returned truthy value; input value unchanged
(s/conform (s/conformer str) 1)
=> "1" ;; returns (str 1)
```

> What is the "unformer" (shouldn't that be an "unconformer") used for? I suppose to recreate the original data from the returned "conformed value"?

Exactly, the `unformer` function can be used to reverse any changes made by the conformer using `s/unform`.

```
(s/def ::str (s/conformer str #(Integer/parseInt %)))
(s/conform ::str 1)
=> "1"
(s/unform ::str "1")
=> 1
```

There's an opportunity to simplify your example spec:

```
(defn my-vertex-conformer [v]
  (let [{x ::vtx-x y ::vtx-y} v] ;; don't need validation here
    {:comment "Vertex conforms!" :something (+ x y) :orig v}))

(s/def ::my-vertex
  (s/and ::vertex ;; because the validation is done by (s/and ::vertex ...)
         (s/conformer my-vertex-conformer
                      :orig))) ;; keyword can be used as unform function

(->> {::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0}
     (s/conform ::my-vertex)
     (s/unform ::my-vertex))
=> {::vtx-x 1.0 ::vtx-y 2.0}
```

> Bonus, amazingly no exception here, is this an oversight?
>
> `(conformer map?)`

No, there's nothing wrong here although it might be unusual to use boolean predicate functions like `map?` with `conformer`:

```
(s/conform (s/conformer map?) {})
=> true
(s/conform (s/conformer map?) [])
=> false
```

`(s/conformer map?)` is a spec that takes any value and conforms to true if it's a map, otherwise false.

> where does [spec] come from initially?

The concept of *contracts* has been around a while in various forms e.g. https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract.